# error when call javascript with ajax twice

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

i made online submit and alert the result

this work fine but when i call the function again i have an error and the error appear from my php file (from inspect element : console at google chrome) like this picture[image: error message]

here the ajax code

```
function function_name(id)
{
    Data=$("#data").val();
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "file.php",
            data: {data:Data},
            success: function(html)
            {
                alert(html);
            }
        });
}
```

i write at another page and found the error at this line

```
<button value="edit" onclick="function_name(<?php echo $row['operation_id'];?>)">edit</button>
```

with the same error

**Update**
Here is a part of my HTML Code:

```
<tr>
    <td> <input type="date" name="time" value="2014-03-06" id="time1"/> </td>
    <td> 1 <input name="operation_id" type="hidden" value="1" id="operation_id1"/>  </td>
    <td> <input type="text" name="info" value="t" id="info1" /> </td>
    <td> <input type="text" name="sales" value="1" id="sales1" /> </td>
    <td> <input type="text" name="Debit" value="1" id="Debit1" /> </td>
    <td colspan="2">
        <button value="edit" id="edit2" onclick="edit(1);">edit</button>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> <input type="date" name="time" value="2014-03-06" id="time2"/> </td>
    <td> 2 <input name="operation_id" type="hidden" value="2" id="operation_id2"/> </td>
    <td> <input type="text" name="info" value="hello" id="info2" /> </td>
    <td> <input type="text" name="sales" value="1" id="sales2" /> </td>
    <td> <input type="text" name="Debit" value="1" id="Debit2" /> </td>
    <td colspan="2">
        <button value="edit" id="edit2" onclick="edit(2);">edit</button>
    </td> 
</tr>
```

Here is my **JavaScript Code**:

```
function edit(editid)
{
    edit=$("#edit2").val();
    operation_id=$("#operation_id"+editid).val();
    time=$("#time"+editid).val();
    info=$("#info"+editid).val();
    sales=$("#sales"+editid).val();
    Debit=$("#Debit"+editid).val();
    $.ajax(
    {
        datatype:"html",
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/edit_user.php",
        data: {time:time,operation_id:operation_id,info:info,sales:sales,Debit:Debit,edit:edit},
        success: function(html)
            {
                //$("#upload_result").html(html).show();
                alert(html);
            }
    });
}
```

Comment: I think it should be  =>  data: {data:Data},

Comment: There may be problem in your "file.php" File

Comment: @PratikJoshi so what i should do ?

Comment: I think it's because of `Data` is inbuilt function. Try using some other name for `Data` like `Data1`

Comment: this is not my code it's just copy and at my code there are no data

Comment: @Santosh Pradhan please see the question again i add where the error

Comment: @robert What do you mean ***this work fine but when i call the function again*** Are you telling that when you click on the button at the first time you will see the `alert` and after that when you click it once again you are getting the error?

Comment: @Pavlo yes i mean that exactly the first time the code work and database update , alert appear  but then nothing happen and error appear

 and if i refresh the page it's work again once

Comment: Could you add this line `dataType: "html"` into your ajax method and see if the error is gone?

Comment: so will be `datatype:"html",type: "POST",...`

Comment: no unfortunately i add this code and don't work

Comment: Can you show your HTML with `<tr>` and what is `$row['operation_id']` is it just an index of your `tr` 'cause I think that the problem could be with it (of how are you passing it as a parameter into your function)

Comment: @Pavlo see here the script 41.131.251.7
it's my pc

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49242/discussion-between-robert-and-pavlo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In accordance to our discussion in the chat you have the following `JavaScript` function:

```
function edit(editid)
{
    edit=$("#edit2").val();
    operation_id=$("#operation_id"+editid).val();
    time=$("#time"+editid).val();
    info=$("#info"+editid).val();
    sales=$("#sales"+editid).val();
    Debit=$("#Debit"+editid).val();
    $.ajax(
    {
        datatype:"html",
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/edit_user.php",
        data: {time:time,operation_id:operation_id,info:info,sales:sales,Debit:Debit,edit:edit},
        success: function(html)
            {
                //$("#upload_result").html(html).show();
                alert(html);
            }
    });
}
```

So, you have the same names for your `function` and `variable` as `edit`. 

**Solution**
Solution to resolve this issue will be just rename your function `edit` to some other name - as an example to `edit1`

Answer (score 0):

just try this

```
function function_name(id)
{
   var Data=$("#data").val();
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "file.php",
            data: {data:Data},
            success: function(html)
            {
                alert(html);
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Should be

```
function function_name(id)
{
    Data=$("#data").val();
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "file.php",
            data: {data:Data},
            success: function(html)
            {
                alert(html);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: I already told him .,Check my comment ,posted before 10 minutes ago.

Comment: Then it seems some problem in php code, What response you are getting ? Can you please share.

Comment: can you remove 'id' from function parameter and check ?

Comment: please see the question again i add where the error